# How can I block event invitations from a specific friends list?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events, friend-list

I know how to [block event invitations from a specific friend](https://www.facebook.com/help/211763458854062). Is there any way to do the same for a specific friends *list* in Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. You have to go into settings menu (the right simbol on the top bar);
2. Then go to the block settings at the left bar;
3. Insert the name of your friend you want to block the invites the third field)

In the image you can see the three steps in my italian version on facebook

Comment: Thanks, but does it work for friend lists?

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not

Answer (score 1):

- Log into your Facebook account and choose "Privacy Settings" from the drop-down menu at the top
- Next, click "Manage Blocking" next to the last option, "Blocked People and Apps."
- This will bring you to the settings page for adding friends to your restricted list and blocking Facebook users, as well as blocking app and event invites.

Please read [here](http://www.cio.com/article/2402951/social-media/facebook-tip--how-to-block-annoying-app-and-event-invites.html) it has a detailed information